# Scale overriding SVG width and height attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, scale

I have an SVG element with a defined width and height, like `<svg width="100px" height="100px"></svg>`, filled with various elements.

I want to have a kind of "zoom" feature, where a particular region of the SVG is zoomed in on to fill the whole SVG element.

I planned to do this with the `scale` and `translate` attributes, i.e. by applying `scale(x)` to the SVG element and then calculating what I need to translate by in order to have the desired region remain visible.

I expected this would keep the SVG at 100x100px and simply hide any element outside this region. However, this doesn't happen; the whole SVG element just gets bigger instead, even though the dimensions are explicitly defined as attributes.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding the way that scaling and SVG dimensions work, does anyone know how I can achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can warp the svg with a div element and use overflow: hidden.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden">
  <svg width="100" height="100" style="transform: scale(4);">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
function setViewBox(vbx){
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox",vbx)
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px" height="200px" id="svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" fill="white" onclick="setViewBox('0 0 100 100')"/>
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" onclick="setViewBox('0 0 50 50')"/>
  <rect x="60" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="green" onclick="setViewBox('50 0 50 50')"/>
  <rect x="10" y="60" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" transform="rotate(45,25,75)" onclick="setViewBox('0 50 50 50')"/>
  <path d="M50 100L75 50L100 100z" fill="yellow" onclick="setViewBox('50 50 50 50')"/>
</svg>
```

or more like that?

```js
var last=null
function setTransform(evt,trs){
  reset()
  svg.appendChild(evt.target)
  evt.target.setAttribute("transform","scale(2 2) translate("+trs+")")
  last=evt.target
}
function reset(){
  if(last) last.removeAttribute("transform")
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px" height="200px" id="svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" fill="white"  onclick="reset()"/>
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" onclick="setTransform(event,'0 0')"/>
  <rect x="60" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="green" onclick="setTransform(event,'-50 0')"/>
  <rect x="10" y="60" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" transform="rotate(45,25,75)" onclick="setTransform(event,'0 -50')"/>
  <path d="M50 100L75 50L100 100z" fill="yellow" onclick="setTransform(event,'-50 -50')"/>
</svg>
```